# AllowAnonymous not working with Custom AuthorizationAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, attributes, asp.net-web-api

This has had me stumped for a while.  None of the commonly encountered similar situations seem to apply here apparently.  I've probably missed something obvious but I can't see it.

In my Mvc Web Application I use the Authorize and AllowAnonymous attributes in such a way that you have to explicitly open up an action as publicly available rather than lock down the secure areas of the site.  I much prefer that approach. I cannot get the same behaviour in my WebAPI however.

I have written a custom Authorization Attribute that inherits from System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute with the following:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyAuthorizationAttribute : System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute
```

I have this registered as a filter:

```
    public static void RegisterHttpFilters(HttpFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new MyAuthorizationAttribute());
    }
```

This all works as expected, actions are no longer available without credentials.  The problem is that now the following method will not allow the AllowAnonymous attribute to do it's thing:

```
[System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [GET("/"), System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public Link[] Index()
    {
        return new Link[] 
        { 
            new SelfLink(Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri, "api-root"),
            new Link(LinkRelConstants.AuthorizationEndpoint, "OAuth/Authorize/", "authenticate"),
            new Link(LinkRelConstants.AuthorizationTokenEndpoint , "OAuth/Tokens/", "auth-token-endpoint")
        };
    }
}
```

The most common scenario seems to be getting the two Authorize / AllowAnonymous attributes mixed up.  System.Web.Mvc is for web apps and System.Web.Http is for WebAPI (as I understand it anyway).

Both of the Attributes I'm using are from the same namespace - System.Web.Http.  I assumed that this would just inherit the base functionality and allow me to inject the code I need in the OnAuthotize method.

According to the documentation the AllowAnonymous attribute works inside the OnAuthorize method which I call immediately:

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
```

Any thought's would be really appreciated.

Has anyone encountered this problem before and found the root cause?

Comment: Make sure you use `System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymousAttribute` and not `System.Web.Http.AllowAnonymousAttribute`. It happens to me and I realised it three hours later...

Answer (score 101, accepted):

In the AuthorizeAttribute there is the following code:

```
private static bool SkipAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    Contract.Assert(actionContext != null);

    return actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any()
               || actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
}
```

Include this method in your AuthorizeAttribute class then add the following to the top of your OnAuthorization method to skip authorization if any AllowAnonymous attributes are found:

```
if (SkipAuthorization(actionContext)) return;
```

Comment: found the same problem when I added a custom AuthorizationFilterAttribute and this solved it.

Comment: Be aware that this code has counter-intuitive behavior: an `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on the controller will **override** any authorization attributes on the method.  To prevent this, you can add another custom attribute check for the `ActionDescriptor` against `IAuthorizationFilter` (or whatever base class/interface you're using) and only skip authentication if that is false when the anonymous controller is true.

Comment: True, but I'd argue that is a bit of a design issue as well.  If you are mixing secure and non-secure actions on the same controller it's time to move things around.

Answer (score 38):

**ASP.NET MVC 4:**

```
bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true)
                         || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);
```

**or**

```
 private static bool SkipAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        Contract.Assert(filterContext != null);

        return filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true).Any()
               || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true).Any();
    }
```

Soruce: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous

Comment: User asked for web api behavior, not mvc.

Comment: @LeandroTupone: When you use AllowAnonymousAttribute in the code rather than referencing the System.Web.Mvc, use System.Web.Http; then it should be fine.

Comment: I came here hoping I could adapt posters issue to the same issue I am having in MVC.  Leaving satisfied thanks to this answer.

Answer (score 22):

In my case, none of the above solutions worked.
I am using .Net Core 3.1 with a custom `IAuthorizationFilter` and I had to do the following:

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any()) return;
```

Answer (score 4):

Using MVC 5
Steps to overcome this issue:-
1. Update your Anonymous attribute of WebAPI project and make it like

```
[System.Web.Mvc.AllowAnonymous]
```

2. Now go to your custom attribute class and write the code

   ```
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext filterContext)
   {
       if (filterContext == null)
       {
           throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Access Token Required");
       }
       base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
       if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any())
       {
           return;
       }
       if (filterContext.Request.Headers.Authorization != null)
       {
           var response = 
    PTPRestClient.GetRequest(filterContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.ToString(), 
    "api/validate/validate-request");
           if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {
               throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
           }


       }
       else
       {
           throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Access Token Required");
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Using C#6.0 
Create a static class that extends the ActionExecutingContext.

```
public static class AuthorizationContextExtensions {
    public static bool SkipAuthorization(this ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {    
         Contract.Assert(filterContext != null);
         return filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true).Any()|| filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true).Any();
    }
}
```

Now your override filterContext will be able to call the extension method, just make sure they are in the same namespace, or include the proper using statement.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthorizeCustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
        if (filterContext.SkipAuthorization()) return;// CALL EXTENSION METHOD
         /*NOW DO YOUR LOGIC FOR NON ANON ACCESS*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for ASP.NET Core 2+ and ASP.NET Core 3+.
Add it into IAsyncAuthorizationFilter implementation:

```cs
private static bool HasAllowAnonymous(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    var filters = context.Filters;
    return filters.OfType<IAllowAnonymousFilter>().Any();
}
```

And check like this:

```cs
public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    if(HasAllowAnonymous(context))
        return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I must be using a different version of the .net framework or web api but hopefully this helps someone:

```
        bool skipAuthorization = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any() || actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
        if (skipAuthorization)
        {
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyAuthorizationAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                bool skipAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true) ||
                    filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute), true);

                if (skipAuthorization) return;

            }
            else filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
}
```