# AllowAnyonmous attribute not honored in IAuthorizationFilter in .net core web api

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a new Web API built with .net Core with a custom authorization filter.  I need to bypass this filter for a handful of actions but otherwise require it globally. How do I get MyAuthFilter to honor the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization] attribute on method UserController.Post?

Authorization Filter:

```
public class MyAuthFilter : IAuthorizationFilter {
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context) {
        //do some auth 
    }
}
```

Registration of Auth filter globally in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc(options => {
        options.Filters.Add(new MyAuthFilter());
    });
}
```

Attribute decoration on user controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize] //only want anonymous on single action within controller
public class UserController { 

    [HttpPost("login")]
    [AllowAnonymous] //this is not honored - MyAuthFilter.OnAuthorization is executed
        public JObject Post([FromBody] JObject userLogin) {

        }
}
```

Comment: Logically, it would be something in the implementation of your custom auth filter, which you've neglected to include.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You cannot access the custom attributes in the custom auth filter context.ActionDescriptor without using System.Net.Reflection

Comment: Who says you need to? The whole "filter" part of this is that it's a pipeline. Something in your custom filter is breaking that pipeline, such that further steps are not being invoked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595723/allowanonymous-not-working-with-custom-authorizationattribute

Comment: Yes but I need to know what action descriptor is being called if I perform this in the Authorization Filter - are you suggesting a do it solely based on Controller and Method name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in [`AuthorizeFilter`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Authorization/AuthorizeFilter.cs) has the following lines:

```
// Allow Anonymous skips all authorization
if (context.Filters.Any(item => item is IAllowAnonymousFilter))
{
    return;
}
```

FWIW, when you're building your own implementations for these types of things, you need to be careful that your implementation accounts for everything it should. If you look at the source code for `AuthorizeFilter`, you'll see it does quite a bit that yours likely isn't. Often, it's better to simply derive from the built-in implementation and override as necessary, rather than attempting to implement the interface yourself.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking regarding .Net (Core) 5.0 this can be done by looking at the ActionDescriptors EndpointMetaData.

```
if (context.ActionDescriptor.EndpointMetadata.OfType<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any())
            return;
```

Answer (score 4):

For .net core 3.1 you can check for `IAllowAnonymous` on the endpoint.

```
// context is AuthorizationFilterContext
var endpoint = context.HttpContext.GetEndpoint();
if (endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>() != null)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This change is explained in the update notes found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnetcore#authorization-iallowanonymous-removed-from-authorizationfiltercontextfilters).