# CustomAuthorizeAttribute - HttpActionContext instead of AuthorizationContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I'm attempting to create a custom authorize attribute in MVC4/Razor and am having an issue with the "AllowAnnoymous" attribute running under the custom authorize attribute (it seems to ignore it). That's all fine and dandy, as I found a solution (see below) to that by checking if the controller or action contain an allow anonymous attribute and then allow pass through if so.

However, I'm seeing that when I create the "AuthorizeAttribute" class and attempt to implement "OnAuthorization" override, it sets the object handlers to a type of "AuthorizationContext" but in the below example and many others i've found on here, it seems the "AuthorizationContext" should not be used - instead it should be "HttpActionContext". Though I tried to replace it with "HttpActionContext" and the override then fails saying there is no suitable method. Any ideas on what I'm missing/doing wrong?

[Example Found Here (By Jammer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595723/allowanonymous-not-working-with-custom-authorizationattribute)

```
private static bool SkipAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    Contract.Assert(actionContext != null);

    return actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any()
               || actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
}

public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
}
```

My Code

```
private override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) // Not sure how to change this to HttpActionContext
{
    if (filterContext == null) throw new ArugmentException("filterContext");
    if (!AllowAnnonymous(new HttpActionContext()))
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnAuthorized);
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any ideas on what I'm missing/doing wrong?

First of all, you are looking at an example that uses the [Web API `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) instead of the [MVC `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs). MVC and Web API are separate frameworks and neither will recognize the other's attributes. This is also the reason why you have a different context type in your `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Secondly, the reason your custom `AuthorizeAttribute` doesn't recognize `AllowAnonymousAttribute` is because you are overriding the logic that does that check in `OnAuthorization` (along with other important logic that deals with output caching). If you instead override `AuthorizeCore` and return true/false, then you will not skip this important logic.

If you need to change where the user is redirected, you can override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`, which only executes when authorization fails.

Finally, if you need to access the `ActionDescriptor` to scan for your own attributes, it is passed into `OnAuthorization` via `AuthorizationContext.ActionDescriptor`. Unfortunately, it is not passed into `AuthorizeCore` automatically, but you can work around this by setting it to `HttpContext.Items` in `OnAuthorization` as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32254851/).

Comment: Well - that definitely explains it. I suppose I didn't look into the different authorize attribute/didn't realize the WebAPI used a separate one from MVC. Is it possible to use the System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute in this scenario vs MVC's? I will also check out the "AuthorizeCore" override, as I definitely want to be able to use the anonymous attributes (without having to hodgepodge things).  I sincerely appreciate the explanation!

Comment: `Is it possible to use the System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute in this scenario vs MVC's?` No, but it is unclear why you would want to. If you want to share business logic between them, you can either create a single class that implements both `System.Web.Mvc.IAuthorizationFilter` and `System.Web.Http.IAuthorizationFilter`, or you could create a common service that is injected into both filters (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32254851/) for info on how to use DI with AuthorizeAttribute.).

Comment: Interesting - I think this will work for me based on my testing with the provided link/explanation. Thank you for the help!