# Custom Authorization Filter has exception in run time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

I'm using my custom authorization filter as it's here
[How do you create a custom AuthorizeAttribute in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464359/how-do-you-create-a-custom-authorizeattribute-in-asp-net-core)
but in run time get this error:
*"InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'papillon.Common.RoleRequirementFilter' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.'.
"*
**Should I change some code in my startup.cs ?!?!**

this is my AuthorizationFilter

```
public class RoleRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string[] _rolesNames;

    public RoleRequirementFilter(string[] roleNames)
    {
        _rolesNames = roleNames;
    }
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Support"))
            return;

        foreach (var item in _rolesNames)
            if (context.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(item))
                return;

        context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        // context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

this is my TypeFilterAttribute

```
public class RoleRequirementAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public RoleRequirementAttribute(string[] roleNames) : base(typeof(RoleRequirementFilter))
    {
        Arguments = roleNames;
    }
}
```

this is my startup.cs

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

// ...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}").RequireAuthorization();

    endpoints.MapRazorPages().RequireAuthorization();
});
```

and this is how I use it in my controller

```
[RoleRequirement(roleNames:new string[]{Roles.Admin1, Roles.Admin2, Roles.Center1})]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`TypeFilterAttribute.Arguments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.typefilterattribute.arguments?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is the array of objects that will be passed to the constructor of the filter you are constructing. Your filter has a single constructor parameter `roleNames` which happens to be a string array. But by setting `Arguments = roleNames` you are effectively telling the framework to pass *each role name* as an individual argument to the filter’s constructor. But since your filter does not have a variable number of string parameters (but just a single string array parameter), this will not match up.

So instead, you should adjust your type filter to pass the string array itself as the sole argument to your filter:

```
public class RoleRequirementAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public RoleRequirementAttribute(string[] roleNames) : base(typeof(RoleRequirementFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { roleNames };
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u, now I have another problem when use it for controller , [AllowAnonymous] in action does not work

Comment: @Soheil Custom authorization filters will not be skipped by default if the `[AllowAnonymous]` is present. If you want to apply that behavior to your authorization filter, you will have to check for it explicitly in the same way, the `[Authorize]` filter works. See [this answer on how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13595881/216074).

Answer (score 0):

you can define your roles as enum, then use ResultFilterAttribute in order to accept any inRole Users like this:

```
public class UserAuthorization : ResultFilterAttribute
    {
        RolesEnum[] _roles;
        public UserAuthorization(RolesEnum[] roles)
        {
            _roles = roles;
        }
        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
           
            // if not in role throw exception
            base.OnResultExecuting(context);

        }
    }
```

in above any controller you can use this attribute like this:

```
[UserAuthorization(new RolesEnum[] { RolesEnum.Admin1, RolesEnum.Branch1,RolesEnum.Center1 })]
    public class MyController : Controller
```